# Convert a json string to array of key-value pairs in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON string that I load into a Spark DataFrame. The JSON string can have between 0 and 3 key-value pairs.

When more than one kv pairs are sent, the `product_facets` is correctly formatted as an array like below:

```
{"id":1,
  "productData":{
  "product":{
  "product_name":"xyz",
  "product_facets":{"entry":[{"key":"test","value":"success"}, {"key": "test2","value" : "fail"}]}
 }}}
```

I can now use the explode function:

```
sourceDF.filter($"someKey".contains("some_string"))
  .select($"id", explode($"productData.product.product_facets.entry") as "kvPairs")
```

However when only one key value was sent, the source JSON string for entry is not formatted as an array with square braces:

```
{"id":1,
  "productData":{
  "product":{
  "product_name":"xyz",
  "product_facets":{"entry":{"key":"test","value":"success"}}
 }}}
```

The schema for product tag looks like:

```
|    |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- product_facets: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- entry: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- product_name: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I change the entry to an array of key value pairs that is compatible with the explode function. My end goal is to pivot the keys into individual columns and I want to use group by on exploding the kv pairs. I tried using `from_json` but could not get it to work.

```scala
    val schema =
    StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("entry", ArrayType(
          StructType(
            Seq(
              StructField("key", StringType),
              StructField("value",StringType)
            )
          )
        ))
      )
    )

sourceDF.filter($"someKey".contains("some_string"))
      .select($"id", from_json($"productData.product.product_facets.entry", schema) as "kvPairsFromJson")
```

But the above does creates a new column kvPairsFromJson that looks like "[]" and using explode does nothing.

Any pointers on whats going on or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: You have two kinds of data: one which its 'product_facets' is an array and another which its 'product_facets' is a string. Am I right? You're trying to load both and address them as a single-kind field (product_facets-wise). Is that the case?

Comment: @nir-hedvat Yes, that is correct. One is an array and in other cases it is a string and I want to treat them both as an array to be able to use the explode function.

Comment: This is not feasible using a simple SQL query because of the fact that Spark cannot address data with multiple schemas (both read & write). You should use UDF to achieve this. Take a look at this https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html. Just pass the field that holds the data and always return an array for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one approach could be :
1. Create a udf which takes `entry` value as json string, and converts it to `List( Tuple(K, V))`
2. In udf, check if `entry` value is array or not and do conversion accordingly.

The code below explains above approach:

```
// one row where entry is array and other non-array
val ds = Seq("""{"id":1,"productData":{"product":{"product_name":"xyz","product_facets":{"entry":[{"key":"test","value":"success"},{"key":"test2","value":"fail"}]}}}}""", """{"id":2,"productData":{"product":{"product_name":"xyz","product_facets":{"entry":{"key":"test","value":"success"}}}}}""").toDS

val df = spark.read.json(ds)

// Schema used by udf to generate output column    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val outputSchema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
  StructField("key", StringType, false),
  StructField("value", StringType, false)
)))

// Converts non-array entry value to array
val toArray = udf((json: String) => {

  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

  val jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  jsonMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  if(!json.startsWith("[")) {
    val jsonMap = jsonMapper.readValue(json, classOf[Map[String, String]])
    List((jsonMap("key"), jsonMap("value")))
  } else {
    jsonMapper.readValue(json, classOf[List[Map[String, String]]]).map(f => (f("key"), f("value")))
  } 

}, outputSchema)

val arrayResult = df.select(col("id").as("id"), toArray(col("productData.product.product_facets.entry")).as("entry"))

val arrayExploded = df.select(col("id").as("id"), explode(toArray(col("productData.product.product_facets.entry"))).as("entry"))

val explodedToCols = df.select(col("id").as("id"), explode(toArray(col("productData.product.product_facets.entry"))).as("entry")).select(col("id"), col("entry.key").as("key"), col("entry.value").as("value"))
```

Results in:

```
scala> arrayResult.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- entry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = false)


scala> arrayExploded.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- entry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = false)

scala> arrayResult.show(false)
+---+--------------------------------+
|id |entry                           |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |[[test, success], [test2, fail]]|
|2  |[[test, success]]               |
+---+--------------------------------+

scala> arrayExploded.show(false)
+---+---------------+
|id |entry          |
+---+---------------+
|1  |[test, success]|
|1  |[test2, fail]  |
|2  |[test, success]|
+---+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for writing a snippet. Thats really helpful. Before i accep this as an answer. I think we would need to handle cases where the input string to "json" can be empty. There are cases where product_facets is an empty string and how would one handle that in the udf?

Comment: I figured it out. the udf needs a slight modification to return an empty array in cases where product_facets is an empty string.